# What is the best way to solve my unusual lighting and wiring challenge?

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch

I moved into a home where the wiring is fairly modern (from the 1980s) but some unusual choices were made in the wiring. At some point, someone put in a lot of single pole switches that didn't work right because the boxes were wired for 3-way lighting.

In the bedroom, I noticed pigtailed hot wires and neutral wires in a 2-gang box. Both switches were wired for 3 way lighting. Thinking the pigtail was a mistake, I decoupled the sets and attempted to wire two switches in separately.  Once I did this, I noticed there was no longer power to the entire bedroom. So I repigtailed everything and closed up the circuit and switch. I confirmed that the 2nd hot was not hot so it needed to be pigtailed to the first one.  That pigtail also provided power to the entire bedroom.

Separately, there is a single gang switch that powers light to the room but is less conveniently located.

Should I try to fix the strange wiring situation? Is it dangerous? How hard is it to run an extra wire to set up the overhead lighting in a 3-way? Is it better to do a wireless solution?

Comment: SkylinkHome has a wireless [kit](http://www.skylinkstore.com/store/us/us-wireless-home-control/starter-kits/skylinkhome-sup-small-tm-small-sup-3-way-dimmer-kit.html) that will work for this. I've used it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You mean single throw switches? 3 way and conventional switches are both single pole, 3 way switches are double throw. As long as the work was done correctly, there is nothing unsafe with using single throw switches even if there are wires for a 3 way setup.

If correctly wired for 3 way, there should be no problem converting to proper 3 way by simply installing 3 way switches. If you want to install lights where none currently exist, you will need to run some wiring, a wireless solution alone will not help since the light fixture has no power at all. You can mount switches where ever and they can communicate wirelessly with the light, but lights need power.

How difficult this would be depends on the specifics of your situation. If you have an accessible attic and the top plate of the wall where the switches are located is accessible as well in the attic, it will not get much easier. Less access means needing to remove finish material for access. Anything in the voids where you fish wires such as insulation or blocking also complicate things.